# Unable to detect non-partitioned USB disk with NTFS file system on Android Marshmallow

Tags: android, filesystems, linux-device-driver, usb-mass-storage

Recently I ported marshmallow on my board. I was exploring USB functions and found an issue:
If I'm using a non-partitioned USB disk with NTFS file system, it's unable to detect it and display a notification as "Corrupted USB disk".

So I tried with other scenarios like, NTFS with partitioned USB disk, FAT32 on non-partitioned USB disk and all these are working fine.
Then I tried to mount it manually from adb shell:

```
# mount -t ntfs /dev/sda /mnt/usbdisk
```

and it's working fine.

But I'm still not able to find why it's not able to auto mount it when I've NTFS on non-partitioned USB disk.
Till now what all I came across is, my usb disk should be detected as DISK when non-partitioned but in case of NTFS file system it's taking it as PART i.e. partitioned disk and getting stuck somewhere.

Any suggestion or leads will be great help.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please make few things....

U said ported to my board.

Talking about Android marshmallow or any other android ....

It is upon ur phone os to support NTFS file system.

Generally in stock Android there is no NTFS file system support.

Although it also depends upon brand , that they are providing NTFS file system support in their is or not.

Generally custom os ROM for ur phone may help.